# How are MongoDB's On-Demand Materialized Views On-Demand vs their Standard Views?

Tags: database, mongodb, materialized-views

According to [MongoDB's Docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/views/#comparison-with-on-demand-materialized-views):

---

> Comparison with On-Demand Materialized Views
>
> MongoDB provides two different view types: standard views and on-demand materialized views. Both view types return the results from an aggregation pipeline.
>
> - Standard views are computed when you read the view, and are not stored to disk.
> - On-demand materialized views are stored on and read from disk. They use a `$merge` or `$out` stage to update the saved data.

---

I have a few questions:

1. Why is the view that's *persisted* (aka ***Materialized***) called "On-Demand"?
2. Why would you ever use a standard view if it's always calculated on the spot (you know, "on-demand")?
3. Does one create a "On-Demand" Materialized View purely by using a `$merge` or `$out` stage?

I asked their new AI chatbot, but it only made the confusion worse:

[image: MongoDB AI chatbot response]

Comment: From my understanding, "on-demand" means you create the view through aggregation `$merge` or `$out`, which requires you to **manually trigger/execute** an aggregation pipeline. The persisted collection is useful for serving as cache/precomputed result if expensive computation is involved. The materialized collection can also be indexed and improve the read performance.

Comment: The standard view can help you save storage space since they are not materialized. Another advantage of the standard view is they can be permission-controlled and improve security.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you "demand": the standard view is computed for every read, so if a "read" is a "demand" that is "on-demand".  A materialized view is only compute when explicitly requested, so if computing the view is a "demand" it is this kind that is "on-demand"

Answer (score 2):

In MongoDB, standard views are predefined aggregation pipelines that are based on a collection. You can apply a set of permissions to a view that differs from the ones for the base collection. So standard views are a handy tool if you want to provide aggregated data to a special user group without granting access to the base collection. The drawback of these views is that the aggregation pipeline is run every time a query against the view is executed.

"On-demand-materialized-views" on the other hand is only a fancy term for a collection that contains pre-aggregated data. It is the responsibility of the developer or DBA to prepare and update the data in the materialized view. Often, this means to run a pipeline with a `$merge` or `$out` stage that writes the data to the materialized view collection, but you could also write the data to the materialized view when adding new documents. This can be done periodically or upon specific events that fit your use case. The "on-demand" stands for the demand of your application and use case in this respect.

From this point of view, "On-demand-materialized-views" is more a pattern than a technology. It is up to you to identify the materialized views that your application needs and the matching mechanism to update the data. A pattern that is closely related is the [Computed](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-computed-pattern) pattern that describes that data that are repeatedly should be pre-computed so that they are available when reading the data.